# Why are there different numbers of possible real zeros?

Tags: functions

For example,

$$f(x)= x^3 - 4x^2 + 6x -4$$

Comes out with *3 real zeros*, or *1 real zero* (and 2 imaginary zeros). I see where the 3 real zeros comes from, but where does the option of 1 real zero come from?

Comment: two of the zeroes are conjugates.

Comment: Draw a picture of a cubic. It will either: a) intersect the $x$-axis thrice (three real zeroes) b) intersect twice, with the curve tangent to the axis at one of the points of intersection (three real zeroes, one repeated twice), intersect once with a critical point there (like $x^3$) (one real zero repeated three times) or d) intersect once, no tangencies (one real zero)

Comment: Well, for example the cubic equation $x^3+x=0$ clearly has only one real zero and two imaginary zeroes. For your problem, note that $x=2$ is a root. Divide by $x-2$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Cubic

Answer (score 1):

You can factor $f$ to get $f(x) = (x-2)(x^2-2x+2)$.  Then set each factor equal to zero to find the roots, $x-2 = 0$ and $x^2 - 2x +2 = 0$.  The first equation shows a real root at $x = 2$ and you can use the quadratic formula on the second equation to get 2 complex roots that are conjugates of each other.  Graphing this on the $x$-$y$ plane will show that the curve only crosses the x-axis once at $x=2$.

I now read your question better.  Complex roots always come in conjugate pairs, which for the cubic equation comes from the quadratic formula.  So, your roots can be $x = a, x = b, x = c$, where $a$ could equal $b$ or $c$ or any combination of equality and they're all real numbers, or you could have $x = a + bi, x = a-bi, x=c$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a quadratic equation $g(x)=0$,  with negative discriminant, and choose a single real number say 8. Now the cubic equation $(x-8)g(x)=0$ has one real root and 2 complex roots; this is the  way all equations with real coefficients having a single real zero arise.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may clear up a bit of confusion:

First, note that a polynomial $p(x)$ will split into $deg(p(x))$ linear factors over $\mathbb{C}$.  Therefore, counting multiplicity, we will have exactly $deg(p(x))$ roots.

Next, if a complex number $z\in\mathbb{C}$\ $\mathbb{R}$ is a root of a polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, then we know that $z^{*}$, its complex conjugate, is also a root of that polynomial.  In other words, complex roots come in pairs.

Thus, we have two cases for the cubic above:

1. There are no complex roots.  In this case, we must have $deg(p(x)) = 3$ real roots (counting multiplicities).
2. There is one complex root.  By the above, it's conjugate must also be a root.  However, we cannot have $3$ non-real roots since they come in pairs, yet we must have $3$ total roots.  Therefore, there is one real root.